# how to connect to another database in symfony other than the configured one

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

I want to connect to another database and/or create a new one in symfony. How can I do that and at the same time get access to the tables of it?

I looked for how to do this inside the app

```
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql 'SELECT * FROM product'
```

but couldn't find any answer.

Comment: doctrine:query:sql does query the same database, doesn't it?

Answer (score 1):

You can't create a database directly from Symfony, but you can use [Migrations](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/DoctrineMigrationsBundle/index.html) to create tables.
If you want to you can even generate the Migrations using the `bin/console` and `doctrine:migrations:diff` to generate migrations based off your Entities.

For the multiple databases you can use [Service Containers](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html) to configure the [Doctrine ORM](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html) then in your code you can grab the specific container and instantiate doctrine from there.

Also if you are interested in doing selects I would take a look at [DQL](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine.html#querying-with-dql-or-sql) as this allows solutions as follows:

```
// This assumes an entity called 'entity' exists.
$query = $entityManager->createQueryBuilder('entity');
return $query->getResult();
```

Comment: how can i use Service Containers for that?? sorry for asking for more details

Comment: Sadly I don't have access to a proper example for now, sorry for that. But you can define multiple containers in `service.yaml`, how we did it was we defined multiple Apps with each their own configuration. So they all would use their own [doctrine configuration](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/configuration/doctrine.html) per configured container. Basically like [This (doctrine example)](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html). I hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes you can create a database directly from Symfony. The developer can modify .env file, after running `composer req doctrine maker` to create any name for a new database as desired, by editing the DATABASE_URL path. What happens from that point is that the developer would then run `php bin/console doctrine:database:create` to create both the database and tables within their given db system. Steps could then follow with creating entities and using migrations:diff to conclude on things.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this, should help: https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html

I short, you can define different entity managers that deals with different database connections

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure multiple entity managers, check [How to Work with multiple Entity Managers and Connections](https://symfony.com/doc/current/doctrine/multiple_entity_managers.html).

Then you can use doctrine commands as below:

```
php bin/console doctrine:database:create --connection=<your_entity_manager_name>
php bin/console doctrine:query:sql --connection=<your_entity_manager_name>
```